# if formula multiple conditions

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I know there is a lot of threads out there about this and I have gone through my share of them looking for an answer.

```
D7 and F7 is formatted to currency Rand
E7 will be text or blank
```

I have 3 conditions in the formula that needs to be met before it provides one of two answers:

```
cell of formula is F7
if D7 is =>50
if D7 is =<-50
if E7 is =0
```

Basically anything higher than `49.99` regardless if it is a minus or not and as long as E7 is a blank cell.

Then it should produce the answer `59`. If all of these conditions are not met it should give `0`.

tried the below formula but does not give me any results, just stays on zero.

```
=IF(AND(D7<=-50,D7>=50,E7=0),(59),(0))
```

Comment: Please note that `as long as E7 is a blank cell` is different from `E7 = 0`. You get `0` from a blank cell but a cell containing `0` is not blank!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your function is saying "If D7 is less than -50 and more than 50", which can't happen.  I believe what you want is to have it say "if it's less than -50 OR more than 50, AND E7 = 0" - which would look more like

```
=IF(AND(OR(D7<=-50,D7>=50),E7=0),(59),(0))
```

Comment: @Jason,  thanks for the quick response,  it makes perfect sense when you state it like that...  works perfectly.  thank you

Answer (score 2):

I know this has been answered already, but here's an alternate formula that will get the job done:

```
=AND(ABS(D7)>=50,E7=0)*59
```

Comment: thanks,  always want to learn more, thats why i like StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Excel 2007:

```
=IF(AND(OR(D7<=-50;D7>=50);E7=0);59;0)
```